# Move UIImage along x- and y-axis

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a control with a knob. This knob should be movable along the x-axis and y-axis **only**.
I have already implemented the following methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I know, that limiting the movement along one axis has to be implemented in `touchMoved`. When I limit the movement along e.g. the x-axis everything work as expected. But how to enable the movement as well for the y-axis? When I enable the second axis, the movement of the knob is not restricted for **only**  this two axis.
Here the part of the `touchMoved` implementation:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint centerPoint = _triggerCap.center;
    CGPoint selectionTriggerCenter = _selectionTrigger.center;


    double distance = ({double d1 = centerPoint.x - selectionTriggerCenter.x, d2 = centerPoint.y - selectionTriggerCenter.y; sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2); });
    if (distance < 100.0) {
        if (fabsf(selectionTriggerCenter.y - currentLocation.y) > 5) {
            centerPoint.y = currentLocation.y;
            _triggerCap.center = centerPoint;
```

Could somebody give me a hint how to enable the movement along these **two** axis **only**?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by only moving along two axises?  Technically, all motion in two dimensions is along the x- and y-axis.  Perhaps you mean you want it to only move in one direction at a time?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I meant. So moving the knob vertically (y-axis) should automatically suppress horizontal movement and vice versa.

Comment: Do you want the user to have to lift their finger and place it back down to change axes, or should they be able to do so "on the fly"?  For example, should they be able to drag the knob in a stair-step pattern without lifting their finger?

Comment: the behavior control is the one like I found in the Beolink app for increasing and lowering the CD player volume: [BeoLink App](http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/beolink/id359002041?mt=8)

(right Screenshot)  

The user do not need to lift his finger but he has to move the knob to the center where the x-axis and the y-axis crosses.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, okay.  So does the knob spring back to the center when it's released?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have implemented CAAnimation in `- (void)touchEnded`. The question is how to suppress the knob movement in x-direction, when the user is dragging the knob vertically and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I can think of to do this, off the top of my head:

In `touchesBegan`, record the location of the first touch inside the knob.  Then, in `touchesMoved`, wait until a touch at least some minimum distance (maybe 15 pixels - play around and see what works best) from the first touch occurs.  Check to see whether it is further from the first touch in the x-direction or in the y-direction.  This will determine which axis movement should be confined to for the the remainder of the current touch sequence.  Set a flag to indicate the axis and from then on use the code that you already have for movement confined to a single axis.  Reset the flag(s) in `touchesEnded` or when the knob returns to within a certain distance from the intersection of the axes.